# Testing old lithium cells with Zanflare chargers, second test shows more capacity?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I've been salvaging 18650 cells.  The first I salvaged was from an old laptop battery that has been laying around for a year or so.  It was still good, as far as I know - the laptop was just no longer around.

I pulled 9 green cells out of it, they all still had some voltage, but I don't remember what exactly.  I charged and tested them in Zanflare chargers.  Normal test, which I believe charges them to full voltage, does a drain to test capacity, then recharges.  The first time I did them, 3 of the cells came out at 1100-1200, 3 around 1000, and 3 around 1450mAh.

I've been using a few cells for various thing and threw them back in the charger. I ran the normal capacity test again just out of curiosity.

Two of the cells in the tester previously ended at 1175, but this time they came out at 1455, and 1292.  The third one was 1256 previously, and this time 1410.

So, are these cells regaining some life after sitting so long?  Or is my tester not as accurate as I would hope?  I guess I could run a 3rd test, but it makes me wonder if at least a second test should always be run on salvaged cells.  Ultimately I'll be making battery packs with these, and if in series I'll want to know accurate mAh ratings.

UPDATE:
Here is a table of 1st, 2nd, and 3rd tests:

```
 1st |  2nd |  3rd 
------------------
1174 | 1455 | 1552
1175 | 1292 | 1323
1256 | 1410 | 1421
```

The last cell isn't as wild, but the first two seem strange.

Comment: Is 'zanflare' a brand name? Capital 'Z'? Or is it something else? Capitals matter.

Comment: @Transistor Yes it is a brand of charger/tester.  4 cells at a time.  Can be found on amazon.

Comment: My best guess is the ESR is recovering with "exercise", under a moderate discharge load some capacity ends up lost to heat via the ESR, and cycling cells can reduce this on the short term after a long discharged period.